# Complexified Kahler moduli

Tags: string-theory, moduli

The fundamental domain of the complex moduli of a torus can be identified to the upper half plane up to $SL(2,Z)$ transformations $\mathbb{H}/{SL(2,\mathbb{Z})}$, but I don't know why the complexified Kähler moduli in string theory ($ir+\theta, r>0$) should be restricted to the upper half plane up to $SL(2,\mathbb{Z})$ transformations and not to the whole of upper half plane?

Comment: I think Exercise 9.9 of "String theory and M-theory" by Becker and Becker might help. In that exercise, they explicitly show complex structure moduli space is same as Kahler moduli.

Comment: Thanks Hare, but they only compute the metric on the complex structure moduli which is SL(2,Z) invariant. I know that the T-duality for n-dimensional torus is O(n,n;Z) and for n=2, we have O(2,2;Z)~SL(2,Z)×SL(2,Z)where the first SL(2,Z) act on the Kahler moduli. When I posed this question, I had forgotten the role of the T-duality action to restrict the Kahler moduli.